# Model's changes for Algolia not showing in the rails console in PRODUCTION

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algolia

I have a model as bellow:

```rb
class Note < Record
  include Shared::ContentBasedModel

  algoliasearch disable_indexing: AppConfig.apis.algolia.disable_indexing do
    attributes :id, :key
    [:keywords, :tags, :description, :summary].each do |attr|
      attribute [attr] do
        self.meta[attr.to_s]
      end
    end
    attribute :content do
      Nokogiri.HTML(self.meta["html"]).text.split(' ').reject { |i| i.to_s.length < 5 }.map(&:strip).join ' '
    end
    attribute :photo do
      unless self.meta["images"].blank?
        self.meta["images"].first["thumb"]
      end
    end
    attribute :slug do
      to_param
    end
    attribute :url do
      Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.note_path(self)
    end
  end
end
```

I am using [AlgoliaSearch](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-laravel) gem to index my models into the Algolia's API and when I was trying to `index` the model with some long `content` I get the following error:

> **Error:** Algolia::AlgoliaProtocolError (400: Cannot POST to https://XXXX.algolia.net/1/indexes/Note/batch: {"message":"Record at the position 1 objectID=56 is too big size=20715 bytes. Contact us if you need an extended quota","position":1,"objectID":"56","status":400} (400))

After this, I removed  **EVERYTHING** as the following, BUT I am still getting the **exact same error**!!

```rb
class Note < Record
  include Shared::ContentBasedModel

  algoliasearch disable_indexing: AppConfig.apis.algolia.disable_indexing do
    attributes :id
  end
end
```

It seems that Rails does not update the cached models.

**Envirnoment:** `production`
**Rails version:** `v6`
**Question:** Why is this happening & how can I clear cached model?

---

**Note:** I have tried everything, including removing the `tmp/cache` folder but it does not go away!

Comment: Your AlgoliaSearch links to a deprecated Laravel (PHP) library. Did you perhaps mean to use https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-ruby or https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails ?

Comment: @JustinWorkman I am already using these.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the object's size itself is bigger than some max allowed size.

> objectID=56 is too big size=20715 bytes

Contact https://www.algolia.com/ (as the suggest)

> Contact us if you need an extended quota

Comment: I already know that, not really helpful! You haven't read the question well.

Answer (score 0):

How do you check your code? Are you entering in rails console on your server? Might it be that you run an old release instead of the new one, in the case if you use Capistrano or Mina for deploy?

Comment: I exit & re-enter into the console

Comment: If it is Capistrano or Mina you need to re-enter into a release folder `cd ../current` then enter into the console.

Comment: unfortunately, it's not!

Comment: If you `cat` your file with `Note` class it shows you an updated version of the file?

Comment: It might be that `spring` is enabled in your environment. Try to set an environment variable `export DISABLE_SPRING=1` before run rails console.

Comment: of course, the `cat` shows the changes. Also, I am not using `spring`.

Comment: I've set up a new Rails 6 application with Algolia. Under `production` environment everything works fine after I re-enter into Rails console, code reloads each time and index gets updated.

Comment: please have a model with lots of content in it.

Comment: This is the model I tested:

`class Note < ApplicationRecord
  include AlgoliaSearch
  algoliasearch do
    attributes :content do
      2_000_000.times.map { |i| i }
    end
  end
end
`

Comment: Please test this `class Note < ApplicationRecord include AlgoliaSearch algoliasearch do attributes :content do 2_000_000.times.map { |i| i }.join end end end` note the *JOIN* method.

Comment: @dariush The same result. My flow to check: 1. Add big content to an attribute. 2. Enter into Rails console, execute indexing. 3. Get the error. 4. Exit from Rails console. 5. Comment/remove this string ` 2_000_000.times.map { |i| i }.join`. 6. Enter into Rails console, execute indexing. 7. Everything is OK.

Comment: OK, so you got the error? is there any other field to `reindex` beside the `content`?

Comment: No, just `content`, code reloading works fine. It seems that something strange in your environment.

Comment: Try to have something **with value** beside the content in your model that gets push into the Algolia API